# compare huge text files using vba

Tags: vba, text, excel

I gotta serious problem here.. any kind of help is much appreciated!!

I have two huge text files (130 MB)each with thousands of records in each. I need to compare the two files using vba or by any means and generate a spreadsheet which includes the header and with two additional columns. The two additional columns will be the file name and in the next column it should display in which particular column is error. Each record will be having multiple discrepancies. One file can have the records which cannot be found in the other file. So this condition should also be recorded in the spreadsheet.

Example:

```
Media Events: Taking one record from each.
00000018063|112295|000|**0009**|

PROL:
00000018063|112295|000|**0013**|
```

In the above example, the records are from two files. The highlighted ones are the differences between the records. So the output should be like this..

```
HH_NUMBER     | CLASS_DATE  |   MV_MIN  DURATION   File Mismatc     Mismatch Reason
00000018063   |   112295    |    000    **0009**   Media Events     Mismatches in DURATION
00000018063   |   112295    |    000    **0013**   PROL             Mismatches in DURATION
00000011861   |   112295    |    002      0126     Media Events     missing in PROL file
```

Comment: For better readability can I suggest you simplify your example to maybe four columns?

Comment: what is it that you are EXACTLY asking? Because for now it just looks like you have to sort out a flow chart to understand with what locig and process you can solve the issue. The select a language and start coding phase isnt the first thing now...

Comment: To get a meaningful answer please read the FAQ with instructions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and a personal favorite of mine: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried

Comment: Floris: I have reduced the columns..hope this helps in understanding.

Comment: @K_B: i tried searching the forum but could not found a solution for my problem.. i have modified the example..hope this helps in better understanding.. I just need to compare the two text files and extract the mismatches present in the two files.

Comment: you will probably not find a single place with the complete solution for your multilayer/multistep problem, not on SO and not on the internet. I suggest you start to dissect it into small steps/subproblems and I will guarantee you 100% that for each such step a solution is on SO and a thousandfold on the www. I also have a gut feeling that by then you dont require much from SO/www. However if you are truely searching for a complete solution from a single source (aka "program me this") please find a freelance software architect/programmer (not on SO)...

Comment: @MohitBagadia you could surely do this with formulas, no need for VBA

Answer (score 2):

It seems there are three problems here:

1) Find matching records (first column) between two files.

2) Compare records that match on the first column - if there is a difference, record what the difference is

3) If a record exists in one file but not the other, record that.

I am going to assume that the two "huge files" are in fact separate sheets in the same excel workbook, and that the records are sorted on the first key. This will speed up processing significantly. But speed is a secondary concern, I assume. I also assume there is a third sheet where you put the output.

Here is an outline of VBA code - you will have to do a bit of work to get it "just right" for your application, but I hope this gets you going.

```
Sub compare()
Dim s1 as Worksheet
Dim s2 as Worksheet
Dim col1 as Range
Dim col2 as Range
Dim c as Range
Dim record1 As Range, record2 As Range, output As Range
Dim m
Dim numCols as Integer

numCols = 5 ' however many columns you want to compare over

Set s1 = Sheets("Media")
Set s2 = Sheets("Pro")
Set output = Sheets("output").Range("A2")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
s1.Select
Set col1 = Range("A2", [A2].End(xlDown));
s2.Select
Set col2 = Range("A2", [A2].End(xlDown));

On Error Resume Next
For Each c in col1.Cells
  m = Application.Match(c.Value, col2, 0);
  If isError(m) Then
    ' you found a record in 1 but not 2
    ' record this in your output sheet
    output.Value = "Record " & c.Value & " does not exist in Pro"
    Set output = output.Offset(1,0) ' next time you write output it will be in the next line
    ' you will have to do the same thing in the other direction - test all values
    ' in 2 against 1 to see if any records exist in 2 that don't exist in 1
  Else
    ' you found matching records
    Set record1 = Range(c, c.offset(0, numCols))
    Set record2 = Range(col2.Cells(m,1), col2.Cells(m,numCols))
    ' now you call another function to compare these records and record the result
    ' using the same trick as above to "go to the next line" - using output.Offset(1,0)
  End If
Next c
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with formulas:

See

- [MS KB: Use Excel to compare two lists of data](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/use-excel-to-compare-%20two-lists-of-data-HA001103915.aspx)
- [Me Excel.com - Creating a list of non-matching values](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/48743-creating-list-non-matching-values-excel-2000-a.html#post223814)
- [ExcelExperts.com - Extracting non-matching entries from two columns in a third column](http://excelexperts.com/extracting-non-matching-entries-two-columns-third-column)

To give you an idea, basically, if you have two lists in columns A & B, you could use formulas like below in columns C and D to show the matching or non-matching:

In C1,

```
=If(isna(match(A1,B:B,0)),A1,"")
```

and, in D1

```
=IF(Isna(Match(B1,A:A,0)),B1,"")
```

both copied down.

**FURTHER READING:**

- [Excel Index Function and Match Function - Contextures MVP](http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions03.html#IndexMatch)
- [Excel VLOOKUP and Index & Match - Excel User MVP](http://www.mrexcel.com/articles/excel-vlookup-index-match.php)
- [Excel User MVP - Excel’s Best Lookup Method: INDEX-MATCH](http://exceluser.com/blog/465/excels-best-lookup-method-index-match.html)